# Shared Dependency for two Deployments on Wildfly

Tags: java, deployment, wildfly

I have two webapps, which are deployed within the same wildfly. Both webapps should share certain libraries, which are not part of the wildfly modules.

To keep the deployment non-dependent on the specific wildfly, I would prefer not to provide the shared libraries via the wildfly-module system (I am aware, it is possible to user-define modules).

My approach was to simply put the library in the deployment directory along with both webapps and reference them within the respective jboss-deployment-structures. This, however, has failed.

I tried to embed the library within a war and reference it via

```
<module name="test.war" />
```

it would not work, as the module is not found. I have found a document from redhat which lead me to thinking this might work: [Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/development_guide/class_loading_and_modules)

I also testet putting the bare jar within the deployment dir and referencing it via resource-root:

```
<resources>
  <resource-root path="my-library.jar" />
</resources>
```

This bootet but the classes from the library are not visible to the deployment.

So my question is: Is there a way to deploy a library within the deployments dir on wildfly an use it from an EAR/WAR Deployment?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are avoiding the usage of modules.  You can easily script the installation of these using `jboss-cli` or other tools.  Having said that, would you ever want your deployments to have different versions of the common library?  Is it so large that it takes up too much disk and/or memory?  If it's not too heavy you may be trying to optimize for little benefit.

Comment: We consider deployment of out application in environments, where jboss-cli might not be available. Currently we pool both applications into the same ear, which leads to non-trivial build times (simply for packaging the ear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple mistake, re-reading the manual solves it.

If you reference a deployment from the `deployments` directory, you have to specify you do so. So, accessing `b.war` from `a.war`, you have to provide a jboss-deployment-structure which reads

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="deployment.b.war" />
</dependencies>
```

If you do so, webapp A can access all java classes defined in webapp B.